# Java Google Drive API without client secrets or new project

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, credentials, google-developers-console

In order to get started with google drive in java I have to

1. Enable the API in my google drive
2. create new project there and download client secrets.json file
3. Use that file in my project folder and do stuff

But applications like WhatsApp are able to upload chatbackups to google drive directly without asking the user to do any of the above steps.

in my application I request the user his/her email address and I have to work with that to access that persons google drive.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think that applications like Whatsapp havent done that?  The only way to use Google apis its to register your application in Google so that google knows which applications are accessing their api and can shut you down if you start spamming them.  So Whatsapp if they can write to google drive have a google client.

You cant use client login anymore with google apis it was shut down in 2015 so requesting email and password from your users isnt going to work.  You need to authorize them with Oauth2.

## anwser

1. the project in Google developer console identitfies your application to google you cant use google apis without it.
2. client secrets is used for hybrid authorization method with Oauth2.  The only method that doesnt use a client secret is implisit login which is for client side languages like javascript.  you cant avoid that.
3. `Use that file in my project folder and do stuff`  you dont use that file in your project to do stuff. You use that file in your project to request access of users and identity your application to google.
4. Your users authorize your application to access their google drive account using Oauth2 you will only be allowed to use it within the (Scopes) of authorization that you have requested of your users.   If they dont grant you write access you cant write to their account.

Comment: I understand now. But what about the client secrets.json file? How do I get that file from my client without actually asking their google drive?

Comment: The clientsecret.json file is created by you the developer and is associated with your application.  If you are hired by someone to create this application then you will need to contact them and ask them to create the client for you.   Users of the application do not need a client secret json file this is only associated with the application itself.  You request access of the users with Oauth2 to access their drive account.  Values from within the file(Client id and client secret) are sent along with the request to identify your application to both your Users and Google.

Answer (score 0):

Applications like WhatsApp request permission to the user to access their Google Drive. You can't access the user's Drive without asking their permission.

The secrets.json file is intended to use only in your own application [1].

From the web, the only way to obtain user's permission to access their drive is implementing the Google Sign-in in JavaScript [2], this will prompt the consent screen requesting to the user permission to access their Drive (You could set only-read scopes). For mobiles, you can also implement the Google Sign-in [3].

[1] https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started#auth

[2] https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

[3] https://developers.google.com/identity/choose-auth